# Como fazer um estrutura de decisão para fechar uma janela?

Tags: java, swing

No código abaixo, eu quero que ao escolher `sim` a janela feche e ao escolher `não` a janela permaneça aberta.

```
private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    int Confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Encerrar?","sim ou nao", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (Confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (Confirm == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

Não dá erro nenhum, o problema é que ao escolher `sim` a janela fecha. Até aí correto, mas ao escolher `não` ela fecha do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Que erro deu na sua tentativa?

Comment: nao da erro nenhum...
o problema e que ao escolher sim a janela fecha.. ate ai correto...
mais ao escolher não ela fecha do msm jeito..

Comment: Vlw galera mais ja deu certo akie.. OBG..

Comment: Netobass, pode publicar a solução como resposta abaixo?

Comment: if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Encerrar?","sim ou nao", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
} else {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)
}

Comment: como nao tenho 10 pontos ainda akie no forum entao n posso definir a resposta ainda..

Comment: @Netobass pode sim. Não precisa de pontos para deixar resposta. Procure em baixo `Publique sua resposta`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu crio um método privado(Private void) ConfirmarSaida, e depois só invoco ele toda vez que precisar usar os Eventos formWindowClosing ou KeyPressed as vezes, assim seu sistema economiza codigo e fica menor e facil de entender =)  .

```
private void ConfirmarSaida(){

        JOptionPane sair = new JOptionPane();
        int Sair = sair.showConfirmDialog(null,"Você deseja sair do programa?","Sair",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
      if(Sair == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
       //    System.exit(0);
       this.dispose();

      }else{
         if(Sair == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){

         }
      }


}
```

Ah! e não esquece de na configuração da JFrame ou JInternalFrame ou seja lá oque for alterar, a SetDefaultCloseOperation para DO_NOTHING(Não fazer nada), assim, quando vc clicar no X da janela ele vai apenas utilizar sua JOptionPane, se vc deixar DISPOSE ou EXIT_ON_CLOSE na SetDefaultCloseOperation , ele irá fechar mesmo que vc clique não na JOptionPane na condicional de sair.

espero ajudar em alguma coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que usar YES_NO_OPTION, tente o trecho de código abaixo, que eu peguei de um projeto antigo meu. Qualquer dúvida é só retornar.
Abraço

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, 
                "Titulo", "Tem certeza ?", 
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Certeza que você usou isso em um projeto antigo seu? Você colocava o título no lugar do corpo da mensagem e a mensagem no lugar do título? Outra coisa, ele _já está_ usando YES_NO_OPTION.

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi alterando na sua ultima linha do código a parte `"DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE"` para `"DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE"` ficando assim:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```